Request to Elastic search from NodeJS
I am new to Elastic search and node js. I have configured ELK in my PC successfully. I have done basic queries using dev tools in kibana. Also I invoked search method from postman. Everything is working fine. But when I am trying to integrate elastic search in nodejs application, the request to elastic search is getting failed and nothing is returned.
Here is small snippet
const fetchElasticData = async () => {
try {
    if (client.transport.connectionPool) {
      console.log("Elasticsearch client is connected.");
    } else {
      console.log("Elasticsearch client is not connected.");
    }       
    const { body: response } = await client.search({
      index: "mongodb-data",
      body: {
        query: {
          match_all: {},
        },
      },
    });
    console.log("Response :" + response);
    console.log(response.hits.hits);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error searching Elasticsearch:", error);    
  }
};
fetchElasticData()

When I am trying to run this, I am getting output as follows:
G:\server> npm start

> server@1.0.0 start
> node server.js

Elasticsearch client is connected.   
Response :undefined
Error searching Elasticsearch: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hits')
    at fetchElasticData1 (G:\server\controllers\sms_Controller.js:237:26)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

I want to know where I am missing. Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

From your logs I can see that Elasticsearch client is connected. It's nice, it looks like Elasticsearch is up and running.
Response :undefined
Error searching Elasticsearch: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hits'). The error message indicates that response is undefined, hence when you try to access response.hits.hits, it throws an error probably because response is not an object.
Let's diagnose step by step.

make sure Elasticsearch is up and running.

curl "http://localhost:9200" or curl -k "https://localhost:9200" -u elastic:password

Check if the mongodb-data index exist

curl "http://localhost:9200/mongodb-data"

Check if the there is data in your index

curl "http://localhost:9200/mongodb-data/_search"
Note: you can also run the above curl command on your browser like the following.
http://localhost:9200/mongodb-data/_search
If the index exist and there is a data in there please check/share elasticsearch and the node.js debug logs.

when curl command is run on browser the output is displayed as follows
{"took":1344,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":{"value":10000,"relation":"gte"},"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"mongodb-data","_id":"662cbe367474177e8d993634","_score":1.0,"_ignored":["log_entry.keyword"],"_source":                                                                                         and so on many such lines are displyed

@svkvvenky check this => https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/50018
